# Join List1 and List2 to fill fields in List1

Tags: linq

I have two lists say customer and Order which join using the field cust_id.
Customer has another field TotalOrderQty which I need to fill by getting the Sum of all order_quantity values of this customer in a given date range.( by looking up Order table). Please help me to write a query for this using Linq(without using Foreach for each customer).

Also please note that the customer entry should be listed, even if he has  not placed any order in the given date range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this one:

```
var result = Customers.Join(Orders, x=>x.cust_id, y=>y.cust_id, 
                            (x,y) => new 
                            {
                                CustomeId = x.cust_id,
                                TotalOrderQty = x.TotalOrderQty,
                                Date = y.Date
                            }).Where(x=>x.Date>=startDate and x.Date<=endDate)
                              .GroupBy(x=>x.CustomerId)
                              .Select(x=> new 
                                      {
                                          CustomerId = x.Key,
                                          SumTotalOrderQty = x.Sum(y=>y.TotalOrderQty)
                                      });
```

where `startDate` and `endDate` defines you date range.

**Note** I have renamed your lists to `Customers` and `Orders`, because these namings are more meaningfull.